# R: Unpack a function that returns multiple objects to multiple columns of a dataframe

Tags: r

Hopefully I can just explain the issue:

I have a function of the following form which returns two values of interest.

```
return_network <- function(team_id){
   ... [ do something to produce adjacency matrix and network density measures] 

  g <- graph.adjacency(co_occur, weighted=TRUE, mode ='undirected')
  g <- simplify(g)

  return(c(weighted_network_density, g))
```

I then want to iterate over a column in a dataframe, apply the above function, and unpack it to two columns.  I have tried the following:

```
team_measures[, c('weighted_network_density', 'graph_object')]  <- apply(team_measures[, "team_id", drop=F], 1, return_network)
```

However, I get a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , c("weighted_network_density", "graph_object"),  :
  provided 429 variables to replace 2 variables
```

And the resulting dataframe is full of nonsense.

Comment: What are `weighted_network_density` and `g`? are these complex objects or numbers? You also want to be careful with `c()` because it can coerce in unexpected ways

Comment: weighted_network_density is just a numeric value.  g is a graph object from the igraph library.  I am storing each graph object inside a row of the dataframe (perhaps this is bad form, but I can't think of another way of doing it) so that I can later compute relevant network measures from that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a guess at the problem: The output of each step in `apply` is bound as columns, even when you apply over rows, so the result is transposed from the way (at least I) would expect.  My simple example below doesn't reproduce your error since it So if we have this data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(dog = c(1,2,3), cat = c(4,5,6), fish = c(7,8,9))
df
  dog cat fish
1   1   4    7
2   2   5    8
3   3   6    9
```

If we apply a function by rows that returns 2 values, we get a matrix with 2 rows:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) c(x['dog'], x['cat']))
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
dog    1    2    3
cat    4    5    6
```

If we leave it as a matrix, we can pass it into 2 columns of a data frame without an error message, but it will coerce it in a strange way that  gives a nonsensical result:

```
df2 <- df
df2[,c('cat', 'fish')] <- apply(df, 1, function(x) c(x['dog'], x['cat']))
df2
  dog cat fish
1   1   1    5
2   2   4    3
3   3   2    6
```

If we convert the result to a data.frame before assigning it (which might be happening somewhere in your code) we get a similar error:

```
df2[,c('cat', 'fish')] <- as.data.frame(apply(df, 1, function(x) c(x['dog'], x['cat'])))
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , c("cat", "fish"), value = list(V1 = c(1,  : 
  replacement element 1 has 2 rows, need 3
```

Transposing the result before passing it in silences the error and results in the data being put in the data the right way:

```
df2[,c('cat', 'fish')] <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) c(x['dog'], x['cat']))))
df2
  dog cat fish
1   1   1    4
2   2   2    5
3   3   3    6
```